# endpoint not found in client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, web-services

I have a service (`EmailSender`). This is config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Conn" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=DT.DBTest;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>      
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="DT.myapp.Services.PremieraInteraction">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP"
                  contract="DT.myapp.Services.IPremieraInteraction"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
      </service>
      <service name="DT.myapp.Services.EmailSender">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding"
                  contract="DT.myapp.Services.IEmailSender"
                  behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>       
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

In the other (asp.net mvc) application I want to call this service. This is proxy class:

```
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    [System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(ConfigurationName = "IEmailSender")]
    public interface IEmailSender
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendRegistrationEmail", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendRegistrationEmailResponse")]
        void SendRegistrationEmail();

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendETicket", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendETicketResponse")]
        void SendETicket();

        [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendTestEmail", ReplyAction = "http://tempuri.org/IEmailSender/SendTestEmailResponse")]
        void SendTestEmail();
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    public interface IEmailSenderChannel : IEmailSender, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel
    {
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
    public partial class EmailSenderClient : System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<IEmailSender>, IEmailSender
    {

        public EmailSenderClient()
        {
        }

        public EmailSenderClient(string endpointConfigurationName) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName)
        {
        }

        public EmailSenderClient(string endpointConfigurationName, string remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public EmailSenderClient(string endpointConfigurationName, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(endpointConfigurationName, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public EmailSenderClient(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) :
            base(binding, remoteAddress)
        {
        }

        public void SendRegistrationEmail()
        {
            base.Channel.SendRegistrationEmail();
        }

        public void SendETicket()
        {
            base.Channel.SendETicket();
        }

        public void SendTestEmail()
        {
            base.Channel.SendTestEmail();
        }
    }
```

And, how I make call:

```
Binding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.None);
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://localhost:12736/EmailSender.svc"));
EmailSenderClient client = new EmailSenderClient(binding, endpointAddress); 
client.SendTestEmail();
```

But, I get error:

```
There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:12736/EmailSender.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
```

The `InnerException` says:

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
```

Where is a error?
Thanks.

Comment: It's telling you that your service (`EmailSender`) is not running (at least not on port 12736 on your local computer).

Comment: I checked it, the service is runing and showing in a browser

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the same type of binding on the client as you are on the server. They are different (service uses `WebHttpBinding` and client uses `BasicHttpBinding`)